# How to use comboBox in asmx.cs to create a Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

I have basic knowledge to create a web service using asmx.cs
and consume from any client application.
I want to create a Web Service using asmx.cs in .NET 3.5 using Visual Studio 2010.
For the following program,By default it gives textBox to take input from user.
But I want to use comboBox to take input from the user.
The result will be displayed as xml output.
I want to do a Web Service program where one city from ComboBox will be taken as input
and the temperature will be shown as xml output.
This code gives only textBox as input.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Services;
    namespace WebService1
    {
        public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {
            [WebMethod]
            public string GetCityByZip(int Zip)
            {
                return "City Name = XYZ, Temperature = 30 Degree";
            }       
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you're talking about is this html to test your web service methods, right?

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_nuQwSyDoLk8/RvWnnpahW8I/AAAAAAAAAJw/UTFuJmCx5M0/s1600-h/WS3.bmp

This test ui is generated automatically based upon your service's WSDL.
The input types are based on the methods your service exposes. So if there's a method like `CityInfo GetCityInfo(string cityName)` in your service, there will be a textbox with input type `string` (as you already noticed). If you're exposing a method like `CityInfo GetCityInfo(int cityId)` the input type will be an `int`.

What's not possible, is to put a combobox there, as the service is autogenerated and has no knowledge which cities are selectable.

What you can do, is expose several methods and build a ui yourself (which you should do anyway).

```
public interface IYourServiceInterface
{
    City[] GetCities(); // returns all possible cities

    CityInfo GetCityInfo(City city); // returns detail Infos about a concrete city
}
```

Comment: <pre>
namespace WebService1
{
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetCityByZip(int Zip)
        {
            return "City Name = XYZ, Temperature = 30 Degree";
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public interface IYourServiceInterface
        {
            City[] GetCities(); // returns all possible cities

            CityInfo GetCityInfo(City city); // returns detail Infos about a concrete city
        }
    }
} </pre>

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'City' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) G:\2nd Sem\Web Services\My WebService Projects in .NET\WebService1\WebService1\Service1.asmx.cs 18 13 WebService1

Comment: Error 2 The type or namespace name 'CityInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) G:\2nd Sem\Web Services\My WebService Projects in .NET\WebService1\WebService1\Service1.asmx.cs 20 13 WebService1

Comment: Error 3 The type or namespace name 'City' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) G:\2nd Sem\Web Services\My WebService Projects in .NET\WebService1\WebService1\Service1.asmx.cs 20 34 WebService1